# Using *ngIf and *ngFor together. Is there any other option than what I am using currently?

Tags: angular

I want to use something like below

```
<div *ngIf="true" *ngFor="let order of orders">
  <li></li>
</div>
```

I googled but there is nothing i found.

So I used below

```
<div *ngIf="true">
   <div *ngFor="let order of orders">
      <li></li>
   </div>
</div>
```

The question is; is there any better way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. Use **ng-container**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <div *ngFor="let order of orders">
      <li></li>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Reason: when you use **ng-container**, the element will not be added to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two structural directives in the same element. That is because the expressions `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` are microsyntax that will be expanded to the following statements respectively.

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="true">
  <div></div>
</ng-template>
```

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-order [ngForOf]="orders">
  <li></li>
</ng-template>
```

So if you use two directives, the [microsyntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) expression wouldn't recognize which directive to expand.

The second option of using two different tags (or `ng-container` tag like other answers mentioned) to apply the directives is the correct way to use it.

---

Looking at this expansion also explains why the `else` clause in a `*ngIf` microsyntax expression is wrapped using `ng-template` tag.

---

One more additional titbit. Most of the punctuation marks in the microsyntax expressions are optional.

For eg.

```html
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
```

is the same as

```html
<div *ngIf="condition else elseBlock">
```

And

```html
<li *ngFor="let user of users; index as i; first as isFirst">
```

is the same as

```html
<li *ngFor="let user of users index as i first as isFirst">
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use the special `ng-container` tag. This will not result in an actual html element, but into a comment:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
   <div *ngFor="let order of orders">
      <li></li>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```